# Files, Months, Modules and Pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, file, module, calculator, pseudocode

I am on the final question of a test exam paper and I have become lost in the creation of the algorithm. My defining diagram looks fine however I just can't work out the order in which to calculate the month aspect.

The question is as follows:

> A file of transaction records includes details such as:
>      - The number of customer who made a purchase in one day
>      - The total value of purchases made in one day
>      - The date of the day
>
> Write a modularised algorithm that uses the information in this file to calculate the total number of customers for each month and the total value of purchases for each month. This information should be recorded a file.
>
> Provide a defining diagram, an algorithm written in pseudocode, and two desk checks for this problem statement.

I am stuck at where to start.

Comment: So you want us to help cheat in exam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about the data structure.

You need to read the input stream, read the date, find the old totals for that month, and add the new number of dollars and days back into the total. (Wherever I say "month", I mean month+year for clarity).

A simple array by month would work, but as the number of months is variable this would require the program to read the input twice to see the array range, or hold them all in memory, both of which are potentially impossible. And it is poor structure for other reasons.

Next step up is the linked list holding a data structure which includes the month and the totals as values. But this would require you to find if the month already appears in the list which is O(n) for every line of input.

One more step up. Hold the month/amount in binary tree sorted (indexed) by month - a "sorted list". To find the appropriate month is order log(months in the input stream), which can't be too big, as even 10 years is only 120 months. This has the benefit that you won't have to sort the data again for the output report, and is probably what they want you to use.

Probably the most efficient structure is what is sometimes called a "Dictionary". Overkill unless you have thousands of months. http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary explains this data structure. Other environments have similar things; it is a variation to a standard hash table. Different Dictionary classes have helper functions to tell you the number of values, list the keys, tell you if a key already exists etc - the sort of thing you need. You would use the month/year as the key and number of dollars and number of customers as the stored values. Dictionaries are constant time, so they are efficient (but overkill I suspect).